# tensor flow 2.0 when take gradient; error says no gradient provided for any variables

Tags: tensorflow

Hey I'm switching from old version of tensor flow and consider a simple linear regression model us

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dtype = "float32"

# define my model here
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(2,name='l1'),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu',name='l2'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])



# create the train data
x_train = np.asarray([[2,3],[6,7],[1,5],[4,6],[10,-1],[0,0],[5,6],
[8,9],[4.5,6.2],[1,1],[0.3,0.2]]).astype(dtype)

# true weights and bias
w_train = np.asarray([[2,1]]).astype(dtype)
b = np.asarray([[-3]]).astype(dtype)

# create response 
y_train = np.dot(x_train, w_train.T) + b


# do prediction and define loss
predictions = model(x_train)
loss = lambda: tf.keras.losses.mse(predictions, y_train)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
opt_op = optimizer.minimize(loss,var_list = model.trainable_weights)
```

Now it raises Error states `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['sequential_1/l1/kernel:0', 'sequential_1/l1/bias:0', 'sequential_1/l2/kernel:0', 'sequential_1/l2/bias:0', 'sequential_1/dense_1/kernel:0', 'sequential_1/dense_1/bias:0'].`

This is so weird because I have the neural network as trainable variable and it has passed during forward procedure. I went to the tutorial but it looks like all new implementation requires manually call gradient function and apply gradient to the optimizer.

The older way, by define operation can automatically take care of this. I kind of want to keep using this way. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tensorflow 2.0, you need use the `tf.GradientTape` context to calculate the gradients, and then apply gradients on your model's variables.

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    # do prediction and define loss
    predictions = model(x_train)
    loss = tf.keras.losses.mse(predictions, y_train)
    grad = t.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, model.trainable_variables))
```